# Pandas: GroupBy re-use of the calculated index

Tags: python, pandas

Ideally I would like to reuse a GroupBy object to improve performance of an intensive operation.

I have a DataFrame containing multiple classifying columns and a value column, I wish to be able to conduct groupby operation on various column combinations, consider the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Build some data to work with:
sim_elements = 1e6
sims = 1e5
class_dict = {0:'A', 1:'B', 2:'C', 3:'D', 4:'E'}

d = {'Year': np.random.randint(1, sims+1, size=sim_elements),
     'Month': np.random.randint(1, 12+1, size=sim_elements),
     'Day': np.random.randint(1, 29, size=sim_elements),
     'Sid': np.random.randint(1e6, size=sim_elements),
     'Class': [class_dict[i] for i in 
               np.random.randint(len(class_dict.keys()), size=sim_elements)],
     'Value': np.random.uniform(size=sim_elements) * 1e6}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# Execute a groupby operation across all columns and sum over the Value column.
gb = df.groupby(('Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Class', 'Sid')).agg({'Value': np.sum})
gb
```

If I apply an operation to the Value column I would then like to recalculate the groupby operation:

```
df.Value *= np.random.uniform(0,2, size=sim_elements)
gbn = df.groupby(('Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Region', 'Sid')).agg({'Value': np.sum})
```

This is slow when conducted across large values for sim_elements, and I am performing this operation hundreds of times per run. 1e6 takes around 4 seconds, 1e7 takes around 50 and I need to support at least 2e7 elements efficiently.

I think the calculated groupby MultiIndex should be re-usable to re-calculate the new agg functions (np.sum is an example), but I can't work out how to apply it. How would one most efficiently reuse a groupby method on a dataframe of the same shape and columns structure multiple times?

Comment: Why do you do the `agg` chained with the GroupBy? You can make gb an *actual* groupby object, and then use it to perform multiple aggregation functions to get different results.

Comment: True and I often do, but in this instance I want to be able to use the groupby data/construct to apply the operation on a fresh data frame. In actual fact I would want to save the groupby to a hdf and reload it in separate threads, but it doesn't seem possible to save a groupby object to a file.

Comment: Ah, I see .... unfortunately I don't know if that's possible or if it is, how to do it...